# How to prove that every set of two or more numbers has a common multiple or factor?

Tags: factoring

I want to prove this:

> Every combination of two or more real numbers always has a common multiple or common factor.

I'm unsure if this applies only to nonzero integers, or real numbers in general.

Comment: Are you including 1?

Comment: @heather I guess, yeah. Would it be different without 1?

Comment: Whether it applies to real numbers or not depends on how you define multiples and factors of real numbers. If a multiple of a real number is an integer multiplied by that real number, then every set of real numbers has a common multiple: $0$. If you want to exclude $0$, there are sets of real numbers without a common multiple. There are no common integer multiples of $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$, for example.

Comment: I believe that a non-zero integer and an irrational number cannot share a common multiple or factor.

Comment: @TheBitByte, I don't know how you'd do it without one (not because it can't be done, but because I just don't know), but if you can include one, you could do something along the lines of x is any number, and x/1 = x, so any two numbers x and y divided by 1 will equal x and y, therefore since x and y are both divisible by 1, they always have a common factor, etc. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every real number is a multiple of every other real number (except zero). For instance $2.3$ is a multiple of $\sqrt{7}$ since

$$2.3 = \sqrt{7}\cdot\dfrac{2.3}{\sqrt{7}}$$

Similarly, any real number, except $0$, is a common factor of any other real number.

All integers do have a common multiple, their product. That is $a\cdot b$ is a common multiple of both $a$ and $b$. So, for example a common multiple of $2$ and $31$ is $2\cdot 31=62$. Similarly, a common multiple of $a,b$ and $c$ is $a\cdot b\cdot c$.

All pairs of integers have a common factor as well, $1$ (as well as $-1$). Certain pairs of integers *only* have these as common factors. We say they are **coprime** or **relatively prime.** For example, $2$ and $9$ are coprime, but $10$ and $25$ are not, as $5$ is a common factor.

Comment: The examples are there to highlight the proof. It's all there for you. For example $1$ is a common factor of integers $a$ and $b$ because $1\cdot a=a$ and $1\cdot b=b$. That's the proof.

Comment: I can't really understand how I missed such a simple proof! Thanks!